# Will Eureka attempt to restart crashed clients

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am wondering if there is a way to configure Eureka server in Spring Cloud to attempt to restart the clients which are crashed. I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but I think at some point Eureka was capable of restarting the failed clients

Answer (score 2):

No. Eureka is not involved in starting, stopping or scaling services.